# Query to Find Duplicate entries

Tags: mysql, sql, toad

I am looking for an SQL query to give me a list of duplicate entries in a table. However, there are 3 different columns to take into account. First is an ID, Second is a Name, and third is a Date. The situation is that there are multiple Names that are assigned with the same ID, and there are multiple records of those in a day, which makes THOUSANDS of different records per day.

I already filtered it so that only results for the past 7 days will show, but the amount of records is still too much for me to extract. I just want to decrease the number of rows in the output order to properly extract the results.

Sample

```
|--id-|--name--|-------date------|
|  1  |   a    |5-9-2015, 10:00am|
|  1  |   a    |5-8-2015, 10:02am|
|  1  |   a    |5-8-2015, 11:00am|
|  1  |   b    |5-8-2015, 10:00am|
|  1  |   b    |5-8-2015, 10:02am|
|  1  |   c    |5-8-2015, 10:00am|
|  2  |   d    |5-8-2015, 10:00am|
```

expected output

```
|--id-|--name--|
|  1  |   a    |
|  1  |   b    |
|  1  |   c    |
|  2  |   d    |
```

Inclusion of entries without any duplicates are fine. The important thing is to only return a single record of a unique id-name combination for a day.

Thanks in advance for any help that you can give.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?  Please tag your question with the database you are actually using.

Comment: *The important thing is to only return a single record of a unique id-name combination for a day* But your expected output is not considering the date. Else, you will have two rows for 1 as id and 'a' as name.

Comment: use `Group by` command in mysql or sql query

Answer (score 3):

You can get the combinations as:

```
select distinct id, name
from sample;
```

If you want duplicates, using `group by` and `having`:

```
select id, name
from sample
group by id, name
having count(*) > 1;
```

EDIT:

If you want this by date, then add `date(date)` to the `group by` and perhaps `select` clauses.

Comment: Per OP,  *The important thing is to only return a single record of a unique id-name combination for a day*. Your query doesn't consider the date. I see that the expected output is not according to the question description.

Answer (score 0):

To return single `id-name` data per day you can use this:

```
select id, name
from tab
group by id, name, date(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

The DATE() function extracts the date part of a date or date/time expression.

```
select id,name 
from sample 
group by id,name,DATE(date) 
having count(*)>1;
```